# How to access inner dictionary items of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following data structure:

```
mydic = { 
           'q4a1_0' : {'title':'4 Question 1 Answer (01)','choices': ((0,'Very Bad'),(1,'Medium'),(2,'Good'),(3,'Very Good'))},
           'q3a1_0' : {'title':'3 Question 1 Answer (01)','choices': ((0,'Very Bad'),(1,'Good'),(2,'Very Good'))}
         }
```

My question is how can I access 'choices' or 'titles' of any dictionary keys(say 'q4a1_0') directly.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Answer selected based on oldest response. Upvoted others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
mydic['q4a1_0']['choices']
```

Comment: The reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 2):

Access by using the indices.

```
>>> mydic['q4a1_0']['choices']
((0, 'Very Bad'), (1, 'Medium'), (2, 'Good'), (3, 'Very Good'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`mydic` is a dictionary, which has a dictionary in it.  So `mydic['q4a1_0']` gets you to the inner dictionary, and `mydic['q4a1_0']['title']` would get you the `title` key from `q4a1_0`.